# How to get multiple documents by using where_not_in operator in Firebase Firestore database?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

How to get multiple documents from a Collection in firebase if we want to filter using not_in operator with a uniqueId list of documents.

I have a arrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList();
idList.addAll(uniqueIdList);
// now idList have more than 500 uniqueId

Query query = db.collection("my_collection")
            .whereEqualTo("status", "DONE")
            .whereNotIn("uniqueId", idList)
            .orderBy("uniqueId", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .orderBy("createdOn", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

/* FIREBASE DOCUMENTATION SAYS
------------------------------
 Use the in operator to combine up to 10 equality (==) 
clauses on the same field with a logical OR */
```

If the idList object have **more than 10 items**. It **crashes the android application** due to FirestoreException.

So, should we not use where_not_in operator? But I have specific demand of this for the query.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your DB structure and explain what do you mean by an entity?

Comment: I edited the question, and found the answer too. Thanks @Dharmaraj

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to query using where_not_in operator in Firebase then, you have to do some part from client side also. The query has a serious limitation. So here is a solution.

```
// Assume idList contains the uniqueId of documents that you don't want
// Assume status can be DONE or PENDING
// Assume list_objects is the ArrayList you have to pass to Recycler view or list view in your app

if (idList.size() > 0 && idList.size() <= 10) {
    query = db.collection("my_collection")
            .whereEqualTo("status", "DONE")
            .whereNotIn("uniqueId", idList)
            .orderBy("uniqueId", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .orderBy("createdOn", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    // your on success code here
} else {
    query = db.collection("my_collection")
            .whereEqualTo("status", "DONE")
                    .orderBy("createdOn", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    // here we are fetching all data where status is done


    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    List<Object> list_toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

                    list_objects = task.getResult().toObjects(ClassName.class);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list_objects.size(); i++) {

                        Object item = list_objects.get(i);
                        if (idList.contains(item.getUniqueId())) {
                            list_toRemove.add(list_objects.get(i));
                        }
                    }

                    list_objects.removeAll(list_toRemove);
                }
            }

// remove the data manually here and we are now good. There is no other way for now.

}
```

So this is a limitation in firebase, but if we look at the advantages of using firebase firestore DB then it's a trade off.
The rule is that if you cannot filter data using query then fetch with applying filters that are possible then again filter using the Collection Framework (if you are using Java). All things are possible in this DB.